# Vue.js attach text after clicking. how?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-material

I have this Vue Material (Vue.js) tag, with the function

```
<md-button id="" v-on:click.native="requestSelected(request)">


methods: {

        requestSelected: function(request) {
            request.accepted = true;
            console.log(request);

            var card = document.getElementById('text');
            var accept = document.createTextNode("Job selected");

            card.appendChild(accept);

        }
```

I'm trying to add some text on the DOM after clicking, could someone recommend to me some Vue js documentacion to check info please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Vue component, create a data property for your display text:

```
data() {
  return {
    displayText: '',
  }
}
```

Then, just put a reference to `displayText` in your template like so:

```
{{ displayText }}
```

Vue will initially display nothing, since `displayText` is empty, and the automatically update the DOM when `displayText` changes.

You would change the text in the `requestSelected` method like so:

```
requestSelected: function(request) {
  request.accepted = true;
  this.displayText = "Job selected";
}
```

[Here's an example in codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPqbEm)

Comment: THANKS a lot Mate! :)
Works perfectly